# Regex javascript preceded by

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm working with regex in order to obtain a word from a string. I have a css class which has multiple classes like: "foo foo-bar foo-bar2 baz-foo" and I want to extract the word after every "foo-" string. In this case will be an array of two elements: "bar" and "bar2".

Does anyone know any way to do it using regex or, even with a javascript function?

I tried things like: `/foo-\w+/g` or `/foo-\w+-\w+/g` but I'm not an expert of regex.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: you are meaning "after"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to pass data in the class name why not just using the `data-*` attributes?

Comment: `foo-(\S+)`, grab the string inside group index 1.

Comment: Yes @AmitJoki, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually after the word after `foo-`. Use `foo-(\S+)` and the group 1 will contain what you want.

Comment: it's better to use `\S+`

Comment: Yes it depends if OP has word characters that he only wants if not `\S+` is fine for just matching the non-whitespace.

Comment: And what if I want only the word(s) after "foo-"? @AvinashRaj e.g if I have "foo-bar" and "foo-bar-baz" I want to obtain "bar" and "bar-baz". It is possible with a single regex or I have to split the result?